# Workflow Task Process in 2010

Tags: workflow, task-list

I am wondering if there is a way to edit a “collect feedback comments”completed task when all the tasks are complete and the overall task process is complete, with out changing the behavior of the overall task process.

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: And more importantly, are you wanting to change it from within the workflow, or through the UI?

Comment: I wanted to change it through the UI ..workflow status page ; Click on the task that is "completed" and add an additional feedback

Comment: I don't think you can do this without intervening manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually, you can edit task fields in dataview in the workflow task list.  You can even change the Content Type to Task and it will let you change it like a normal task, and switch the content type back.

It would be difficult to do from within the workflow because the workflow doesn't keep track of the IDs of the tasks created within a task process, and you'd have to add code inside the process to make that information available to the workflow.

Comment: Looking for some type of workaround or to allow editing of the Task form.
Is there a way to do that? My users wants to go back to the completed workflow task list or workflow history and supply an additional comments via Comments field like 3 weeks after the workflow completed.

Comment: Changing the content type using datasheet view is the only idea i have.

Comment: thanks Erin, could you please give me a little bit more details on your suggestion? thanks again

Comment: Create a new datasheet view that includes the content type column. Change the content type to "Task." Let users make their changes. Then change the content type back to whatever it was originally.  Alternately (and this idea is probably better than using datasheet view), you could use a workflow to set the content type after the item is approved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489477/sharepoint-change-content-type-in-sharepoint-designer-using-workflow